# How to allow a thread to finish while another thread is sleeping

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sleep

I am writing a C# Console Application that handles multiple threads, but for some of the threads I have to wait for some time while other threads are waiting to finish sleep time for the thread which is in sleep. So how can I achieve parallel programming when one thread is sleeping, but other threads should work at the same time?

A solution that I tried is below. The output which I'm expecting is as `i == 1` is in sleep mode for 1 min till the time other two `i == 2` and `i == 3` should get printed in the meantime.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT
2
3
(after one minute) 1
```

Comment: Take a step back. Explain what you want the program to **do**. Try to avoid using words like thread etc.

Comment: The simplest solution is likely to change `int i = 0` to `int i = 2` and move the logic inside the first `if` after the `for` (this will give you what you want without the need to spin up new threads etc). It is still very unclear **why** you would want to do this though.

Comment: my question is so simple when one thread is in sleep how to run other thread as i'm trying to run it is waiting for other thread to finish

Comment: Part of the issue is that your terminology is wrong. For example you say 'other thread' when there **isn't** another thread involved. Your code only has one. How long have you been programming for in C# (so we can provide our answer at a level that is useful for you)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your simple solution:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            task = Task.Run(() => {
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                    Console.WriteLine("1");
                }
            );

        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
        }
    }

    task.Wait();
}
```

But I'm pretty sure that you need much more understanding, how the threads work. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

As mjwills pointed out, you only have **one thread** here.

When you start an application, this will create one thread, usually it is called the **main thread**. To avoid your program from freezing you tend to try not to `Thread.Sleep()` in the main thread.

That being said when you want to create a new [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) which is similar to a [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8) you can process this way :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task yourTask = Task.Run( () => {
                        // Do Something, like your sleep.
                    });
    yourTask.Wait();
}
```

If you want your task to **run synchronously** (for exemple you **need** to wait that something ends before you can continue your program), I suggest you see the `RunSynchronously()` method from the Task Class in the link above. If you want for it to **run asynchronously** (for example you **don't need** to wait that something ends before you can continue your program), you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

While I know this will downvoted, I can't help but point out the simplest solution to your problem is likely:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    Console.WriteLine("3");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
```

It gives the exact output you are aiming for. It is simple, and easy to read and understand. It doesn't use a loop or an extra thread - but the code in your question doesn't *need* either of those things.